# Five reputation is missing in my SO

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation

Five reputation points are missing in my SO. It is showing only 2109. But it is showing in other SE and Android Enthusiasts as 2114.

Why is it missing? Whats wrong?

[image]

Link from my [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/174328/padma-kumar):

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Someone upvoted [this question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668923/samsung-galaxy-7-gt-p6210-not-detecting-for-usb-debugging) (can't tell when) and yesterday at 21:59 his account got deleted so those 5 points vaporized.

Here is how I know this:

[image: unupvote screenshot]

There is no "-5" as one would expect and this might be considered a bug but I'm pretty sure that's the reason for the missing 5 points.

The reputation in the "Accounts" tab is heavily cached so you still see the old reputation - after you will post new question or answer on Stack Overflow the cache should be refreshed.