# How did I get a -10?

Tags: support, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Five reputation is missing in my SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125461/five-reputation-is-missing-in-my-so)

I just got -10 on several answers that I had posted quite some time ago, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410617/how-to-debug-the-this-c-code/9410689#9410689); the answers have not been edited. What could have happened? Did a user who upvoted get their account deleted or something like that?

When I viewed the particular question, SO showed +9 total upvotes but when I clicked the +9, it become +8/0.

Comment: The dupe provides the most likely explanation

Comment: Yep - my answer in the dupe is relevant in your case as well.. user who voted on some of your answers got nuked - in the past such things were totally transparent and we could not see this happening but now with the new reputation history.. well, it's all out in the open. :)

Comment: I checked the log and it's indeed an "unupvote". Feel free to close this question as a dupe.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A user was deleted - we're now showing those changes in your profile.  I'll be working (hopefully today) on making this show something along the lines of "user removed" in your profile rather than "unupvote" or "undownvote" since that's much more descriptive of what happened.

The current state (first step) was showing you something happened *at all*, if the reputation page doesn't show you why your rep changed...it's not very useful :)

Comment: I also noticed that in case of question unupvote there is no "-5" showing as one would expect. [Screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/NjRCz.png) - or is this different issue?

Comment: *A user who upvoted you had an... unfortunate accident.*

Comment: @Pekka - heh. That phrase reminds me of London underground talking about line closures due to a "customer incident".

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd - the recording of the rep change with a value is new, as of last night.

Comment: There *definitely* needs to be some extra indication besides just "unupvote". I'm totally in the dark about what happened to 410 Rep that I lost today. I have no way of knowing if it was a merged sock, the vote fraud detector, or a deleted user.

Comment: @gnostradamus - serial voting reversals *do* have their own type already.  The user thing is a bit more complicated, but I'm working on it...not entirely sure it's possibly yet.

Comment: It seems this is still in effect? [I had such an impossible `unupvote` today](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11456608/939860). Took me a while to make sense of it. (If indeed that's what's the case.) Basically, "unupvote" is misleading. The information I get from it is: somebody found a flaw in my post and rescinded his upvote. But that's not what happened if a user got deleted.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - Nothing's changed here...your profile is accurate.  The user who upvoted your post at 19:19, before the 19:32 edit was free to remove their upvote after that, because of the edit...they did so today, you'd have to ask them why :)  However, I have upvoted your helpful answer!

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up (and your vote). I forgot to consider the short time slot between the original commit and my edit back in July for the original upvote. Still would be great to distinguish between "unupvote" and "user deleted", even if that's unrelated to my case now.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - when a user is removed it'll *always* show that, never "unupvote"...if someone finds a case where this doesn't happen that's certainly a bug. Given how it works though, that shouldn't be possible...we just hadn't gotten around to implementing "user deleted" as a top item when we first deployed the new rep code.

Answer (score 3):

From you description it looks like an "unupvote" - someone removed their upvote from the answer (or their account was deleted).

This results in the reputation being taken off.

The changes were not visible until [fairly recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/recent-reputation-history-changes).

Comment: If the answer hasn't been edited then the removal of an upvote is unlikely. It's more likely to be either account deletion or the vote fraud script removing votes.

Comment: The answer was edited but not recently. Answered Feb 23 at 9:55 Edited Feb 23 at 10:23 Presumably someone that upvoted between these times could still undo their vote?

Comment: @ChrisF - Quite right. Didn't think about deleted accounts.

Comment: @Martin no that's not possible whatsoever.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd - Why not? I thought after an edit your vote is no longer locked in. Pretty sure I've retracted upvotes on questions in this circumstances before when I've come across an old answer that I can see I upvoted but am no longer convinced by.

Comment: @Martin oh sorry, see now what you mean. If user voted before the edit  and got back after long time in which the post was edited then yes he can undo the upvote. Good point! However Nick confirmed it to be a deleted user so in this case it's not relevant.