# Is it possible to find related post associated with the reputation loss due to "user was removed" message

Tags: discussion, reputation, down-votes, up-votes

I have seen the similar [**post**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126698/how-to-find-the-posts-related-to-lost-reputation-due-to-user-was-removed-messa) here on the site related to the message **`user was removed`** but its not quite clear how to find the related post associated with it.

We can see the post associated with removal of post, is provided with the post heading and/or question. I think the posts associated with this **`user was removed`** message is of the user who is getting this strange reputation loss.

[image: Reputation loss due to removal of post and user]

In the image above we can see the when post is removed the heading is provided, but for the user removed message the heading and/or link is not provided.

Is it possible to find out the related post?

Comment: No, there is no way.

Comment: @Bart is correct and the reason as far as I know is they don't want us to know which user was removed. Plus there's chance that many posts were affected on all kinds of reputation events (upvote, accept, bounty) so it's big headache to find proper display for this.

Comment: As far as I can tell the only reason that this would be useful is purely for curiosity sake, there is no action you can take to do anything about deleted users / votes impacting your reputation. You would find a post that had been impacted by a removed user and you could say to yourself 'hmm, this is a post someone voted on that has since been removed'. i.e. it's not actually useful at all. (Nor would it really be all that interesting either).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way we can track posts associated with "user was removed" message.

As @**Shadow Wizard** commented above in the question, many posts are affected on all kinds of reputation events (upvote, accept, bounty).

Also there are many anonymous users who voted for one of our posts had their account deleted either by their choice or due to violating the network's Terms of Service.

And one thing to remember that this feature goes both ways as we gain points when a user who had downvoted our post get removed.

Answer (score 2):

When a user is removed, all of the affected reputation changes are [consolidated into a single event](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126471/131979), so you cannot see which post(s) were affected because they have been merged.

Besides, even if you could see a list of posts that were affected by the removal of another user, what would/could you do with it? The change has nothing to do with you or your posts, it was due to the *other user*. There is no action needed on your part.