# Why do I get -2 point of reputation from "user was removed", apparently for an accepted answer?

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-accounts

Recently, I got -2 of reputation from a removed user. I was able to track it down to the fact, that I have accepted an answer from a removed user.

The green checkmark is still there and I see no reason to unaccept this answer, but why was the reputation taken away in this case?

P.S. The question and answer that I think is responsible for that: [Switching tocdepth in the middle of a document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395856/switching-tocdepth-in-the-middle-of-a-document)

Comment: Are you sure it's the accepted answer, and not a suggested edit (maybe on an unrelated post) that user might have approved? You can use [this trick](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312191/295232) to get more information.

Comment: (I do think it has something to do with that specific user; in SEDE, his user record is still visible.)

Comment: I found [this approved suggested edit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/89672) where the last user who approved the edit had their account deleted. This revokes the +2 rep from the edit.

Comment: @Glorfindel Thanks for the trick, it seems to be another post ... but I cannot see what happened there (maybe an edit to a now deleted answer ... I edited the original question), the other post being https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295466/latex-compiles-a-to-%c3%a4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your edit on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295466/latex-compiles-a-to-%c3%a4) has been approved by a now-deleted user. You can see this in the [suggested edit itself](https://tex.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/89672):

> Community♦ reviewed this Feb 23 '16 at 13:12: Approve

You'd normally see Community in case of an *improved* edit, but here it took ownership of the approval vote from the now-deleted user. SEDE (which was updated last Sunday) still has information about the deleted user, see [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/1004348).

[image]

If it's fair to lose +2 reputation in this case has been discussed before, e.g. [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311251/4751173).