# Like the mobile app, the full site should show what posts' votes were removed from by a deleted user

Tags: feature-request, android-app, mobile-app

I recently lost some reputation due to a user being deleted on Arqade. On the site, all it says is "User removed (learn more)" as usual, but on the Feed page of the mobile app it shows what post the vote was removed from (one I answered on):

[image: shows which post the vote was removed from]

This is the only [negative reputation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/163757/timmy-jim?tab=reputation) I've earned recently and this appears to be the only spot on the app where it shows the actual post where the votes were removed. It doesn't reveal the user that was deleted specifically, but is the app suppose to show this? If so, it's odd that it is not consistent with the site.

App Version: 1.0.95

Comment: It's a feature of the API, and it provides a [useful workaround](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312191/295232).

Comment: I don't believe this should be tagged with `bug`, since it's by no means clear that the behaviour seen in the mobile app is the same behaviour that was intended for the full site. It's only a bug if it's failing to work as it should. Instead, I think it's more likely that things *are* working as intended on the full site. As such, I think this should be a `feature-request` instead.

Comment: @JasonBassford after having some light shed on this, I agree.  I'll edit the tags.

Comment: @TimmyJim I also took the liberty of updating the title of your question to make it more in line. Feel free to change it back or edit it if I got it wrong.

Comment: @JasonBassford I thought the app was dead, development wise?

Comment: @BruceWayne The app is no longer being developed; it is, however, still being used. I interpret this as a request to have the full site provide information that matches that of the app. I'm always annoyed by seeing I've lost reputation because of users who have left—but never knowing which posts were related. If the app shows that, I'd like like the full site to as well.