# The ability to see which posts lost upvotes when a user was removed

Tags: feature-request, voting, hyperlinks, reputation-graph

When a user is removed who has not cast too many votes, the votes they did cast are reversed. For example, an hour ago, I lost 40 network-wide reputation points because of this reversal (which is extremely frustrating but not what I'm asking about.)

[image]

As you can see in the above image, the post graph tells me why I lost 30 reputation, *but*, unlike the upvote below it, it does not link to the post which was voted on.

*So*, I have no idea which post's had their upvotes removed. I would like to be able to see this. Is it possible to implement this feature?

Comment: [How can I find posts related to lost reputation due to a “user was removed” message?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126698/295232) – that's a [tag:support] question, but I've posted a workaround which you can use in the meantime.

Comment: Also, [40 reputation is peanuts](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10927/116151) ...

Comment: Lots of people have lost reputation due to this particular user deletion. [Here's mine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYNlr.png): 680 on one site plus small change on several others.