# Please let me know which post a users' vote was removed from when a user is removed

Tags: feature-request, deleted-accounts

Here is my previous query: [I got no rep for an upvote while not hitting the rep cap?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125152/155556) which was resolved when it was found that a user was **deleted** therefore it showed as no vote.

Now it looks like this:

[image: -10 from what?]

Can we show **which post** the rep was deleted from (aka which post a vote was removed)?

In this case **I know** which post it is referring to, but in the future I may not.

Can we show:

[image: -10 from there]

Or something like that?

Comment: All the rep you lost from that user being deleted is grouped into one event, so obviously this would not work without splitting it up into separate unupvote events ([again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125989/strange-unupvote-pattern-across-multiple-users)). In this particular case, it was just one vote, but it could have been hundreds.

Comment: @lunboks so have a dropdown of the breakdown of which posts garnered a rep change.

Comment: It was showing the affected posts in the beginning with "unupvote" as the reason and no rep change, so people complained it's too confusing. [Nick nuked this and revised the way it's showing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125993/152859) to what we see today so even though you do have valid point, I can't see it happening. You can try your luck by commenting on that answer of Nick and asking to make yet another change.. risking his wrath. :)

Comment: I've posted a workaround [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312191/295232); you can find out which posts were affected via the Stack Exchange API.

Answer (score 4):

This would remove the anonymity of voting in many cases, there aren't many users deleted on most sites so it would often be easy to identify who the user was that has been deleted. This would show you which of your posts that user has voted for, abolishing the anonymity of voting.

The vote removal on deletion has the highest impact and visibility for high-reputation users. When those leave there are usually traces of the issues that caused in on the site meta or chat, which means that many people know who was deleted and it's relatively easy to find out. Even if there is no explicit record, many users will notice when a high-reputation user goes missing.

Comment: Huh? That would not show anything at all. I would not know **who** the user is at all....

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA If you notice the user being deleted, maybe. Say a high-rep user ragequits the site and you notice corresponding "user removed" events.

Comment: @lunboks again, if the user **was removed** I have no idea who the heck it is.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA Suppose Jon Skeet ragequits (yeah, as if that's going to happen), and you get `-1670 user was removed`. You'd know.

Comment: @DanielFischer but if it was a sock puppet, I would like to know what was being socked.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA Why would that information be useful to you? Curiosity alone is not a very strong reason for a new feature.

Comment: @aman Yes, but it may already be possible to destroy voting anonymity by the "user was removed" message, though not for realistic scenarios. However, if the posts affected are listed, that may make identification of voter and voting behaviour easier to to deduce. If a user of medium notoriety is removed, and you have say 10 upvotes removed on posts in tags he was active in, that would be an indication of who cast these votes. I think that's about lunboks' point.

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is with being able to identify the voting patterns of a user that has been deleted. It's not like you're going to be able to retaliate against them or anything. They've been ... well, _deleted!_

Comment: @paxdiablo retaliate against what, up-voting for you? Come to think of it, wouldn’t we *gain* rep for a deleted user who had down-voted us?

Answer (score 2):

I was thinking the same thing. Over the years, I’ve seen a few of these and have always wondered which of my posts was affected. It seemed logical to want to see which post I lost or gained (so far only lost) rep on. However to be honest, it just occurred to me that this would be pointless.

When this happens, we don’t lose/gain rep from anything that has to do with the our posts; the change is due to the user, so it doesn’t really matter or have anything to do with us. Obviously, since our rep *does* get affected, we would need to know why it suddenly changed, but knowing the specific post that was affected is useless because there’s nothing to do with that knowledge.

If you lost some rep from a deleted user who had up-voted your post, you don’t need to improve it because that’s not why you lost the rep. If you gained some rep from a deleted user who had down-voted your post, you don’t need to, well *anything*; just be happy about the rep-bump.

There’s really no point to knowing which post(s) were affected.