# Find unupvote of question

Tags: support, reputation

How can I see which of my questions an upvote has been removed? Because there is sudden decrement of 10 in my reputation, and I want to figure out which question the upvote has been removed.

Can I find it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Please let me know which post a users' vote was removed from when a user is removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127247/please-let-me-know-which-post-a-users-vote-was-removed-from-when-a-user-is-remo)

Comment: @NathanTuggy it is not clear to me if the OP sees that reputation event in their rep history. I read it that they observed an un-upvote.

Comment: @NathanTuggy this is not a duplicate because I cannot see reputation change there? no where it mentioned for change of -10

Comment: @rene this is not a duplicate because I cannot see reputation change there? no where it mentioned for change of -10

Comment: A change of -10 can't be linked to a single event on a question. Questions gain +5 for an upvote (and -5 for an up vote but that is not recorded publicly, it is more like the +5 never happened). Please be precise what you;re seeing and what you're looking for

Comment: If you look at [/reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7510657/anthony-winzlet?tab=reputation) (or if it was not SO, switch to the correct site first), is there any event visible in your reputation history that matches with the -10 you see?

Comment: @rene there is no event with -10... and that's why I asked this question... Could you please help me to find out...

Comment: It's also possible that 5 posts which you've suggested an edit to have been deleted (by Roomba, most likely).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't workout what happened to your reputation from your [/users/current/reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current/?tab=reputation) or [/reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/reputation) you can obtain your [full reputation history](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/full-reputation-history) from the Stack API.

That endpoint does require authentication and it is likely to have lots of pages to go through (you can only get 100 results in one call).

I have created a Glitch Application [here](https://se-reputation-audit.glitch.me/) that calls that full reputation history endpoint but it does require you authenticate against that app and that does give the app access to your private data for the duration of your browser session. If you're uncomfortable with that idea, just [remix](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/se-reputation-audit) the application and provide your own [Stack Apps application secret](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication).

For some categories, like user delete, unupvote and voting fraud revesal it will add a link to the post that is/was involved in the voting activity.

Just note it will not and cannot and should not reveal the user who voted. Voting is anonymous, there are no back-doors.

When you run the app your result will look like this:

[image]